# Getting error message installing Firestore pods when using macOS Big Sur Version 11.1

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods, pod-install

I have used Firestore in previous projects before on my old Mac, I've just recently bought a new MacBook Pro and I'm trying to install firestore pods I first set up the pod file and save it with the below code

## Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '10.0'
target 'Demo' do

## Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

use_frameworks!

## Pods for Demo

pod 'Firebase/Auth'

pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

end

Then I go back on Terminal and type pod install, I get many error messages coming up
Is there something I'm not doing correctly or is this an issue because of my new MacBook and does anybody know what I should do to fix this thank you in advance

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.
Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+missing+compatible+arch+in+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...

- CocoaPods compatibility with Apple DTK (Apple Silicon)
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9907 [open] [88 comments]
  a day ago
- Error running project in flutter
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10456 [closed] [1 comment]
  a week ago
- Error when "pod updating Firebase" on Ionic 5 macbook M1 Big sur
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10411 [closed] [6 comments]
  5 days ago

and 5 more at:
[https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C%200x0009%29%3A%20missing%20compatible%20arch%20in%20%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%20-%20%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues&utf8=✓](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C%200x0009%29%3A%20missing%20compatible%20arch%20in%20%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%20-%20%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9907

Answer (score 0):

I am using XCode 11.3.1 on a MacBook with M1 chip, and I solved it by running:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

So, first step is:

```
yarn install
```

then

```
cd ios
```

and

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```